# AWK output formatting and syntax

Tags: linux, syntax, awk, printf

Ive been trying to sort out output using AWK, and have been pretty successful going through some of the stuff on stack overflow until i hit the last part of the command below.

```
-bash-3.2$ find /home/username/www/devdir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf "%TY %Tm %Tb %Td,%TH:%TM,%p,\n" | grep "^$r" | grep Aug | sort -r | awk -F '/' '{print $1,$6","$7}' | awk -F " " '$1, { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n"); }' | head -10
awk: $1, { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n"); }
awk:     ^ syntax error
```

The output looks like the below:

```
2010 08 Aug 28,11:51, Directory Tom,005,
2010 08 Aug 28,11:50, Directory Smith,004,
2010 08 Aug 28,11:46, Directory Jon,003,
```

I want it to look like:

```
2010 Aug 28,11:51, Directory Tom,005,
2010 Aug 28,11:50, Directory Smith,004,
2010 Aug 28,11:46, Directory Jon,003,
```

I woud like to cut the "08" out of it, and sometimes without losing the sorting done earlier. This will change to 09 next month and 10 the following, I believe I can use sed to solve this, however I am not an expert with it. Can someone shed some light as to what I should do to overcome this obstacle?

I've referenced this question to get an idea of what I needed to do: [Sorting output with awk, and formatting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853783/sorting-output-with-awk-and-formatting-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do want do accomplish exactly with this part?

```
awk -F " " '$1, { }'
```

I mean the $1, ...

Regarding the update:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) 08 \(.\+\)$/\1 \2/'
```

should cut this out.

Or more generic:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) [0-9][0-9] \(.\+\)$/\1 \2/'
```

Comment: I want to keep the year (2010).

Comment: I updated my question to clarify how I wanted the output to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your greps into one and all your awks, seds and head all into one `awk` script. Since you're grepping only one month and one year, you don't need to include the `%Tm` in the `find` and you're effectively only sorting by the day of month and time. I'm assuming `$r` is the year.

Approximately:

```
find /home/username/www/devdir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -printf "%TY %Tb %Td,%TH:%TM,%p,\n" | grep "^$r.*Aug" | sort -r | awk -F '/' 'NR<=10{print $1,$6","$7}'
```

By the way, here's how you would do what you set out to do:

```
printf($1" ");for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf("\n")
```

You would print the first field explicitly rather than include it by reference. However, using my suggestions above you shouldn't need to do this.